# Ошибка при многократном вызове функции/передача параметров

Tags: python, функции, dict, параметры, передача-параметров

Есть код, который достает список рецептов из txt файла, обрабатывает его (в этой части вроде бы все в порядке), после этого инфа передается в функцию, которая считает кол-во ингредиентов исходя из кол-ва персон, вот код:

```
dish_name = 1
ing_count = 2
ingredients = 3

cook_book = {}
dish = dish_name

with open('recipes.txt', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        if dish == dish_name:
            title = line
            cook_book[title] = []
            dish = ing_count
        elif dish == ing_count:
            count = int(line)
            dish = ingredients
        else:
            if dish == ingredients:
                data = [x.strip() for x in line.split('|')]
                data[1] = int(data[1])
                cook_book[title].append(dict(zip(('ingredient_name', 'quantity', 'measure'), data)))
                count -= 1
                if count == 0:
                dish = dish_name

def get_shop_list_by_dishes(person_count, dishes):
    for k, v in cook_book.items():
        if dishes.count(k) > 0:
            for i in v:
                x = {}
                x[i['ingredient_name']] = i
                del i['ingredient_name']
                for y in x.values():
                    y['quantity'] = y['quantity'] * person_count
                print(x)
```

Если не вникать в детали, то все работает, но на самом деле есть две ошибки:

1. При вводе **get_shop_list_by_dishes(['Омлет', 'Омлет', 'Омлет', 'Омлет'], 1)** результат будет некорректным, функция просто выведет результат для **одного** 'Омлета', а нужно чтобы **для 4**. Нужно чтобы такой ввод функция воспринимала так же как и **get_shop_list_by_dishes(['Омлет', 4])**.
2. Если вызвать функцию  с одинаковым запросом дважды - будет ошибка. Текст ошибки **x[i['ingredient_name']] = i KeyError: 'ingredient_name'**.
   Как это исправить?

Функция должна возвращать такую структуру данных:

```
{
  'Картофель': {'measure': 'кг', 'quantity': 2},
  'Молоко': {'measure': 'мл', 'quantity': 200},
  'Помидор': {'measure': 'шт', 'quantity': 4},
  'Сыр гауда': {'measure': 'г', 'quantity': 200},
  'Яйцо': {'measure': 'шт', 'quantity': 4},
  'Чеснок': {'measure': 'зубч', 'quantity': 6}
}
```

**Внутри файла txt:**

Омлет

3

Яйцо | 2 | шт

Молоко | 100 | мл

Помидор | 2 | шт

Утка по-пекински

4

Утка | 1 | шт

Вода | 2 | л

Мед | 3 | ст.л

Соевый соус | 60 | мл

Comment: опубликуйте, пожалуйста, небольшой пример вашего `recipes.txt`

Comment: Не понял можно ли прикреплять файлы к вопросу, написал структуру, блюд может быть произвольное количество, но структура всегда такая

Comment: 1. Корректность параметров должна контролироваться вне пределов функции. Решается с помощью класса Counter из модуля collection. 2. Не надо удалять ключ del i['ingrident_name']